# Fetch all records but some condition on filed in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I need `select * from new_entry where batch=2018`.
I tried `query.filter(NewEntry.batch==batch).first()` i got first record in database but i need all columns which is matched to batch.What can I do?

Comment: No..they used filter_by but I'm using filter itself

Comment: That's irrelevant. The main issue in your question and that other one is: "what is the equivalent method to `first()` that fetches all?" And the answer to both is: `Query.all()`. Closing as a duplicate is not a slight on you, but a way to signal future readers that there are existing answers to this same issue elsewhere as well. And the closing part redirects possible additional answers to that single location so that they don't scatter all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using first() you will only get the first result, to get all the results as a list you have to use all()

```
query.filter(NewEntry.batch==batch).all()
```

Comment: Wow .I got the output man.Thank you Alex